# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'function result' String convert to List

Tags: list, flutter, charts

I'm trying to create a chart and i'm using Strings from firestore and i want to convert these Strings to List and use it on the chart. But i'm getting some problems with that, like this type list dynamic is not a subtype of type String on decode of json. How can i solve this problem?
Here's the code:

```
    List<ChartData> convert(String input) {
      List<ChartData> output;
      try {
        output = json.decode(input);
        return output;
      } catch (err) {
        print(err);
        return [ChartData(0, 0)];
      }
    }
    final List<ChartData> list1 = convert(testefinal);
```

and i'm getting this problem

```
The following _TypeError was thrown building Graph(dirty, state: _GraphState#6bec7):
type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'function result'
```

I'm using SyncFusionChart that's why the list type is ChartData, any suggestions or a way to solve this problem? And i'm getting this error when i try to convert the String to List

```
 FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 39)
I/flutter (22157): "[{ChartData(127.49999999999999,25),]""[{ChartData(147.5,25),]"
```

Comment: Could you please provide the JSON that you're trying to parse? You can find out what it looks like by adding print(json) at the beginning of the function.

Comment: It's returning:
I/flutter (22157): Instance of 'JsonCodec'
I